# how can I do multi update with $ symbol in mongo engine

Tags: mongoengine

how can I do multi update with $ symbol with mongo engine in .py file, give  any small example.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Atomic Updates](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.4/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates) in the docs:

```
Foo.objects.all().update(set__bar='baz')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> data = dict(set__real_rate=1, set__rate=1, set__change=1, set__variance=1, set__tags=[], set__cloud={}, set__description='not much')
>>> Grid.objects(id='tv').update(upsert=True, **data)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres examples in the test suite for mongoengine:

https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/tests/queryset.py#L313-382

A quick example:

```
class BlogPost(Document):
    title = StringField()
    tags = ListField()

BlogPost.drop_collection()

BlogPost(title="ABC", tags=['mongoEngien']).save()

BlogPost.objects(tags="mongoEngien").update(set__tags__S="MongoEngine")
```